# Cloud Machine Learning Engine fails to deploy model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have trained both my own model and the one from the  [official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction#deploy_a_model_to_support_prediction).

I'm up to the step to deploy the model to support prediction.  However, it keeps giving me an error saying:

```
"create version failed. internal error happened"
```

when I attempt to deploy the models by running:

```
gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 \
--model $MODEL_NAME \
--origin $MODEL_BINARIES \
--python-version 3.5 \
--runtime-version 1.13
```

*the model binary should be correct, as I pointed it to the folder containing model.pb and variables folder, e.g. `MODEL_BINARIES=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/results/20190404_020134/saved_model/1554343466`.

I have also tried to change the region setting for the model as well, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out your GCS bucket and the trained model needs to be in the same region.  This was not explained well in the Cloud ML tutorial, where it only says:

```
Note: Use the same region where you plan on running Cloud ML Engine jobs. The example uses us-central1 because that is the region used in the getting-started instructions.
```

Also note that a lot of regions cannot be used for both the bucket and model training (e.g. asia-east1).